# how can i add a click event to all markers in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I have a list of addresses to that list I place its markers but I want that when clicking on the marker the address is shown but I cannot add the event to all the markers and it only works with one.

Map loading

```
viewAnnotationManager = binding.mapView.viewAnnotationManager
                binding.mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS){
                    addAnnotationToMap()

                    pointAnnotationManager.addClickListener(object : OnPointAnnotationClickListener{
                        override fun onAnnotationClick(annotation: PointAnnotation): Boolean {
                            viewAnnotation.toggleViewVisibility()
                            return true
                        }

                    })
                    
                    /*pointAnnotationManager.addClickListener { clickedAnnotation ->
                        if (pointAnnotation == clickedAnnotation) {
                            viewAnnotation.toggleViewVisibility()
                        }
                        true
                    }*/
                }
```

Carga los marcadores

```
private fun addAnnotationToMap() {
        createListShop()
        val annotationApi = binding.mapView.annotations
        //val pointAnnotationOptions = annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView!!)
        for (i in 0 until orders!!.shippingData.pickupPoints.size){
            nameShop = orders!!.shippingData.pickupPoints[i].friendlyName
            val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(longitudelist[i], latitudeList[i]))
                .withIconImage(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.marker_location)!!.toBitmap())
            listShop.add(pointAnnotationOptions)
            pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi.createPointAnnotationManager()
            pointAnnotation = pointAnnotationManager.create(listShop[i])
            prepareViewAnnotation(longitudelist[i], latitudeList[i], nameShop)
        }
    }

    private fun View.toggleViewVisibility() {
        visibility = if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun prepareViewAnnotation(longitude: Double, latitude: Double, nameShop: String) {
        viewAnnotation = viewAnnotationManager.addViewAnnotation(
            resId = R.layout.view_marker,
            options = viewAnnotationOptions {
                geometry(fromLngLat(longitude, latitude))
                //associatedFeatureId(pointAnnotation.featureIdentifier)
                anchor(ViewAnnotationAnchor.BOTTOM)
                offsetY((pointAnnotation.iconImageBitmap?.height!!).toInt())
            }
        )

        ViewMarkerBinding.bind(viewAnnotation).apply {
            tvAnnotationMarker.text = nameShop
        }
    }
```

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it, make sure to add the `OnPointAnnotationClickListener` before the `addOnMapClickListener`

```
private fun onMapReady() {
    val annotationApi = binding.mapView.annotations
    pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi.createPointAnnotationManager()
    pointAnnotationManager.addClickListener(OnPointAnnotationClickListener { annotation ->
        viewModel.annotationList.first { it.annotation == annotation }.apply {
            onAnnotationClick(this)
        }
        true
    })
    viewModel.initAnnotations() //here I do some background work then for each annotation I call addAnnotationToMap
}

private fun onAnnotationClick(wrapper: AnnotationWrapper) {
    val pixelPoint = binding.mapView.getMapboxMap().pixelForCoordinate(wrapper.point)
    viewModel.handleEventClick(pixelPoint, wrapper)
}

private fun addAnnotationToMap(wrapper: AnnotationWrapper) {
    bitmapFromDrawableRes(
        requireContext(),
        R.drawable.img
    )?.let {
        val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
            .withPoint(wrapper.point)
            .withIconImage(it)
        event.annotation = pointAnnotationManager.create(pointAnnotationOptions)
        viewModel.annotationList.add(event)
    }
    notifyUserOfEvent()
}
```